# Converting UTC timestamps to the users time zone in ELM

Tags: datetime, timezone, elm

I am working on a calendar written im ELM, that needs to show entries it gets from a backend over a REST interface. All times I get from the backend are in UTC, and I need to show them to the user in the user's time zone.

I implemented this by getting the timezone off the user once at the beginning with the following task:

```
getTimezone : Cmd Msg
getTimezone =
    Task.perform SetTimezone here
```

and stored the result in the model.

Whenever I needed to show the user a timestamp, I used these two functions:

```
formatTime : Zone -> Posix -> String
formatTime zone timestamp =
    let
        hour =
            toHour zone timestamp

        minute =
            toMinute zone timestamp
    in
    (padLeft 2 '0' <| fromInt hour) ++ ":" ++ (padLeft 2 '0' <| fromInt minute)

formatTimeOfIsoTimestamp : Zone -> String -> String
formatTimeOfIsoTimestamp zone isoTimestamp =
    toTime isoTimestamp |> Result.map (formatTime zone) |> Result.withDefault isoTimestamp
```

Now that we had the switch from DST to standard time last week end in Europe, I noticed a problem:

Last week (still having DST) all times within this week were off by one hour because my code was still adding two hours (offset for CEST) to the timestamps while only adding one hour (offset for CET) would have been correct. This week it's the opposite: timestamps of this week and the following weeks are correct, while timestamps of the past weeks are now all incorrect.

I have seen the notes in https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#here that propably are what I have a problem with: `here` does not return the timezone `Europe/Berlin` information but a fixed offset, in my case `Etc/GMT+1` or `Etc/GMT+2` depending on whether DST is active or not at the moment.

My question now is: how do I correctly handle time zones in ELM, if I need to format timestamps distributed over the complete year? Is there any other package, that can help me with this? If required I could also ask the server for the correct timezone of the user (e.g. `Europe/Berlin`), but I don't want to make a server request for each timestamp I need to convert for performance reasons. So I think I need some implementation of the IANA time zone database in ELM.

Comment: What is the type of `SetTimezone`?

Comment: @RobertK.Bell It's the Msg I get when elm sends me back the result of querying the time zone from the JavaScript environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using the fixed offset that `Time.here` provides, an alternative is to pass in the result of `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions)) through the [flags](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/flags.html) at startup.

Using [justinmimbs/timezone-data](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/timezone-data/5.1.2/), parsing it on the Elm side may look something like:

```
TimeZone.zones
    |> Dict.get resolvedTimeZone
    |> Maybe.withDefault TimeZone.zone_australia__sydney
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Problem solved. One note: I had to use `(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolvedOptions().timeZone`, i.e. I had to call `new`.

Comment: Instead of resolving the time zone within JavaScript, the timezone-data package mentioned also provides a function [`TimeZone.getZone`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/timezone-data/latest/TimeZone#getZone) that can request the same information directly from Elm.